# Retrieve connection endpoint for Azure cosmosdb for Postgresql Cluster by CLI

Tags: azure

I am trying to retrieve the connection endpoint (coordinator name) for CosmosDB Cluster by Azure CLI but failed. The commands I tried are:

> az cosmosdb show --name cosmospostgrepreprdjl1 --resource-group ABC
>
> az postgres server show -g ABC --name cosmospostgrepreprdjl1

Both of the above return resource not found but this resource does exist and able to connect by db client. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> Resource not found but this resource does exist:

*Check the subscription to see if the resource is present. If a subscription mismatch occurs, it may result in resource not found issues.*

According to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/postgres/server?view=azure-cli-latest#az-postgres-server-show), there is a `subscription` parameter that can be used to include the subscription when executing the `az postgres server show` command.

I tried the below command as you and was able to retrieve the required information as shown.

```
az postgres server show --name newpser --resource-group <resourcegroup>
```

[image]

I also tried the `az cosmosdb show` command in the below manner and was able to retrieve the required information successfully.

```
 az cosmosdb show --name <cosmosdbaccountname> --resource-group <resourcegroup>
```

[image]

***To retrieve the connection strings, use the AzCLI command***
[az cosmosdb keys list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-keys-list) ***and it worked as expected.***

```bash
az cosmosdb keys list --type connection-strings --name <cosmosdbaccount> --resource-group <resourcegroup>
```

[image]

**Note:** The command `az cosmosdb list-connection-strings` is also used to list the connection strings, but it will be deprecated in the future.

[image]